# How to paginate RecyclerView items?

Tags: android-recyclerview

How to paginate `RecyclerView` items  I want to show for items per page.
this is my `RecyclerView` currently.
[image]

this is what i want to implement.
[image]

How can i achieve this

Comment: This isn't a `ViewPager`, but a `GridLayout`. And posting your requirements doesn't count as a question.

Comment: this is `RecyclView` where items are displayed in `GridLayout`. i want to display four items in a view for another four items I want to swipe right like 'ViewPager'